# flutter: cannot find symbol GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith((FlutterEngine) registry);

Tags: flutter, firebase-notifications

I have this problem :

```
/Users/nameuser/AndroidStudioProjects/app_gp-last_one/android/app/src/main/java/com/example/app_gp/Application.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith((FlutterEngine) registry);
                                            ^
```

symbol:   class FlutterEngine
location: class Application
Note: /Users/nameuser/AndroidStudioProjects/app_gp-last_one/android/app/src/main/java/com/example/app_gp/Application.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

my Application.java

```
package com.example.app_gp;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
 // ...
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
}

@Override
public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith((FlutterEngine) registry);
}

// ...}
```

pubspace.yaml

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
http: ^0.12.2
firebase_core: "^0.7.0"
firebase_auth: "^0.20.0+1"
firebase_database: "^6.0.0"
fluttertoast: ^7.1.6
firebase_messaging:
firebase_analytics: any
flutter_local_notifications: ^3.0.0'
```

how i can solve this problem